# Javascript setInterval function increases speed onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which count downward on click, it's working fine but the problem is when the button "run" is clicked multiple times, the speed of the counter increase.
I have used the "clearInterval" to remove the recent created interval, but it's still not working.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="run">Run</button>
<p class="show"></p>
```

Script

```
$(".run").on("click", function() {
    var myInterval;
    var decrement=5;
    clearInterval(myInterval) ;
    myInterval=setInterval(function decrementNum() {
        decrement--;
        $(".decrement").text(decrement) ;
        if(decrement==0){
            decrement=5;
        }
        $(".show").text(decrement) ;
    }, 2000)
})
```

Comment: Your `myInterval` variable is local to the anonymous function, so on the next click, it won’t be available any more.

Comment: @CBroe the interval event is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **intervalId** is local to the function. Everytime you are adding more and more event listeners. The setInterval's frequency is increasing hence its `speed increases`
Move your variable outside so everytime you `click`, the myInterval accessed is the same.

```
var myInterval;
$(".run").on("click", function() {
    var decrement=5;
    clearInterval(myInterval) ;
    myInterval=setInterval(function decrementNum() {
        decrement--;
        $(".decrement").text(decrement) ;
        if(decrement==0){
            decrement=5;
        }
        $(".show").text(decrement) ;
    }, 2000)
})
```